# Как получить последнюю по дате запись (SQLite)?

Tags: sql

У меня есть таблица `price (id, link, name, cost, date)`. В столбце `name` содержатся имена товаров, в столбце `cost` - цена на соответствующий товар. Эти цены с некоторой периодичностью добавляются в таблицу. Мне необходимо вытащить из таблицы последнюю запись конкретного товара по дате. Как я это могу сделать?

Comment: order by date limit 1

Comment: Последняя по дате = первая по убыванию дат. Первая = limit 1 | first 1 | top 1, в зависимости от диалекта sql. По убыванию дат = order by date desc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM price
WHERE name = 'product_name'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

запрос сначала выбирает все записи с именем товара `product_name`, затем сортирует их по дате в порядке убывания и возвращ. только одну посл. запись с помощью оператора `LIMIT 1`.

Еще вариант:

```
SELECT * FROM price p1 WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM price p2 WHERE p1.name=p2.name AND p1.name='product_name')
```

или так:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM price WHERE name = 'product_name' ORDER BY date DESC) as temp_table
GROUP BY name
```

Еще одно решение может быть функции для вашей СУБД, например `ROW_NUMBER()` в SQL, `DENSE_RANK()` в Oracle или `RANK()` в MySQL.

```
WITH temp_table AS (
    SELECT id, link, name, cost, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC) as rn
    FROM price
)
SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE name = 'product_name' and rn = 1;
```

Предложенный мной ранее запрос с использованием оператора `GROUP BY` может возвращать неожиданный результат, если таблица `price` содержит несколько записей с одинаковым именем товара и датой, так как в этом случае неопределенно, какую из этих записей вернет запрос. Есть несколько других способов решить эту задачу. Один из них - это использование сортировки и оператора `LIMIT 1` в запросе. Например:

```
SELECT id, link, name, cost, date
FROM price
WHERE name = 'product_name'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Этот запрос выбирает все записи с именем товара 'product_name', сортирует их по дате в порядке убывания и возвращает только одну последнюю запись с помощью оператора LIMIT 1.

Другой способ - подзапрос с макс. датой:

```
SELECT id, link, name, cost, date
```

Comment: *Еще вариант:* Не гарантирует единственности возвращаемой записи. *или так:* Явная ошибка. Неполная группировка. *Еще одно решение* Отбор во внешнем запросе для одного продукта - неразумно. Добавьте пояснение, что в такой форме можно получить последние записи сразу для всех или нескольких определённых продуктов.

Comment: Можно предположить, что поле Id является автоинкрементным, тогда в первом варианте нужно изменить сортировку на **ORDER BY date DESC, Id** и получить 1 и последнюю добавленную запись для конкретного 1 "name".